# Star Topology In Mininet

Tags: python, networking, mininet

I am trying to create a star topology in mininet such that for each node n, n connects to a central switch and is able to ping anyone else across the switch. I have developed much more complicated network typologies in mininet yet I am struggling to understand why my code snippet below is not working as expected.

```
start_ip = ipaddress.ip_address("10.0.0.1")
c0 = net.addController()

# Create the nodes without an ip
for i in range(1,num_nodes+1): 
    net.addHost('h%d'%i,ip=None)

# Create the switch
switch = net.addSwitch('s0')

# Connect each host to the switch
index = 0
for host in net.hosts: 

    # Each node's eth0 connects to a different interface on the switch starting at eth0 for index 0
    net.addLink(host, switch, intfName1 = '%s-eth0'%host.name, intfName2 = 's0-eth{}'.format(str(index)))
    host.setIP(str(start_ip))

    index += 1
    start_ip += 1
    
print("Created {} nodes in {} seconds".format(num_nodes, time.time() - start))

net.start()

#Text connectivity with xterm
CLI(net)

#Text Connectivity with ping command provided by mininet
net.pingAll()

#do some work with these nodes (ex: executing python scripts on each with sockets)

net.stop()
```

When building a simulation using this code and testing ping connectivity it works as expected for 51 or less parties.
[image: 30 node ping connectivity test]

However, here is the ping results when creating 52 nodes (1% of pings dropped):
[image: 51 node ping connectivity test]

Of course I am not able to capture an image of the full test but it is only the first node who seems to struggle pinging the other nodes. As the party count increases this issue also becomes more and more problematic. Does mininet have a limit on the number of nodes that can be constructed and attached to a single switch? Is there a better way I could be doing this?

Comment: Dyou can try to divide processes. Just because you don't get out doesn't mean it's not working !

Comment: Could you explain what you mean a little more. I'm just a little bit confused. But I appreciate your feedback!

Comment: Data pipes (python) bandwidth and buffer memory read speed may be disrupted. I didn't see python hardware applications working properly (I've written C as a mandatory(again)). If you examine the module you are using, you'll see that you've opened a lot of virtual files (RAM). Now that the addresses are calling the files, what will check the accuracy of these addresses? It's hard to see if there's an access error or a data error.

Comment: The interesting part is I asked a co-worker of mine to try running this program. For them, they were able to run with 100 parties no problem. My machine has good hardware so I cant imagine it being an issue with memory.

Comment: i am not sure but you can try used all CPU cores for your app. Thing is single core can't handle this(my idea)

Comment: I see what you are saying. I will give this a try sometime soon and I will let you know if it worked or not. Thank you for the advice!